# SQL Server 2017: Delete trigger with transaction

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions

There are 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[user] (
    user_id       INT           NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    user_deleter INT REFERENCES [user] (user_id),
    user_deleted DATETIME2
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.[project] (
    project_id      INT           NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    project_owner   INT           NOT NULL REFERENCES [user] (user_id)
);
```

For dbo.[user] there is a trigger that should delete one (or multiple) user(s) (That is what the while and DELETERSTABLE are for)

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER delete_user
ON dbo.[user] 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO DELETERSTABLE 
    FROM DELETED
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETERSTABLE) <> 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @id INT = (SELECT TOP 1 user_id FROM DELETERSTABLE)
        DECLARE @deleted DATETIME2 = SYSDATETIME()
        DECLARE @deleter INT = (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.[user].user_id FROM dbo.[user] INNER JOIN dbo.[usertype] ON dbo.[user].user_type = dbo.[usertype].type_id WHERE dbo.[usertype].type_name = 'ADMINISTRATOR')
        UPDATE dbo.[user] SET user_deleted = @deleted, user_deleter = @deleter WHERE user_id = @id
        DELETE FROM DELETERSTABLE WHERE user_id = @id
    END
    DROP TABLE DELETERSTABLE
END
GO
```

When I execute the following code: `DELETE FROM dbo.[user]` it works good. But I am trying to add transactions to the trigger (so that it doesn't just delete 2 users and not continue to delete the other 3 for example) like in the attempt I did underneath

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER delete_user
ON dbo.[user] 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
            SELECT * INTO DELETERSTABLE 
            FROM DELETED
            WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETERSTABLE) <> 0
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @id INT = (SELECT TOP 1 user_id FROM DELETERSTABLE)
                DECLARE @deleted DATETIME2 = SYSDATETIME()
                DECLARE @deleter INT = (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.[user].user_id FROM dbo.[user] INNER JOIN dbo.[usertype] ON dbo.[user].user_type = dbo.[usertype].type_id WHERE dbo.[usertype].type_name = 'ADMINISTRATOR')
                UPDATE dbo.[user] SET user_deleted = @deleted, user_deleter = @deleter WHERE user_id = @id
                DELETE FROM DELETERSTABLE WHERE user_id = @id
            END
            DROP TABLE DELETERSTABLE
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            THROW 51001, 'CUSTOM ERROR: delete_user NOT executed', 1
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

When I execute the following code: `DELETE FROM dbo.[user]` I get the next error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__project__project__36FC065D". The conflict occurred in database "***", table "dbo.project", column 'project_owner'

How can i still use transactions while keeping the structure of the 1st trigger

Comment: Why are you doing it as a `WHILE` loop? Why not just do the whole thing in a single statement? You can't declare a transaction into a trigger as it's already inside one; if any part of the trigger fails, the whole transaction is rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't need a `WHILE` loop at all, or any of those variables. The entire trigger could be changed to:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER delete_user
ON dbo.[user] 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE dbo.[user]
    SET user_deleted = SYSDATETIME(),
        user_deleter = (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.[user].user_id
                        FROM dbo.[user]
                             INNER JOIN dbo.[usertype] ON dbo.[user].user_type = dbo.[usertype].type_id
                        WHERE dbo.[usertype].type_name = 'ADMINISTRATOR') --Why do you want the deleter to be a random user?
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id
                      from deleted);
END
GO
```

Note the comment; why do you have a `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY`? Are you happy to mark the deleter as a random user that has the `ADMINISTRATOR` type? (that doesn't seem like intended logic).

To quote my comment under the question as well:

> You can't declare a transaction in a trigger as it's already inside one; if any part of the trigger fails, the whole transaction is rolled back.

So, you don't need to declare a transaction.